# What privileges does a domain user require to use AcquireCrednetialsHandle (Schannel) using LocalMachine certificate store?

Tags: windows, ssl, winapi, schannel

I have a program that can successfully create an Schannel connection when run using a local user id on a Windows machine. My call to `AcquireCredentialsHandle` is not a complex one - fairly vanilla.

```
  credData.dwVersion = SCHANNEL_CRED_VERSION;
  credData.cCreds    = 1;
  credData.paCred    = &pSecLstr->serverCert;

  ss = AcquireCredentialsHandle(NULL,
                                UNISP_NAME,
                                SECPKG_CRED_INBOUND,
                                NULL,
                                &credData,
                                NULL, NULL,
                                &(pSecLstr->hCred),
                                &Lifetime);
```

When it is run using a domain user logged in using RDP, and utilising the LocalMachine certificate store, the call returns `0x00000520 (ERROR_NO_SUCH_LOGON_SESSION)`.

I assume that this means some privileges or security policies are missing on the domain account that would normally be present on a local user ID. I cannot find any documentation about what those privileges or policies might be however.

Anyone know?

Comment: Local machine certificate store is local to the computer and is global to all users on the computer. 
`administrator privileges` are required to install certificates into the local machine store. As far as I'm concerned, you could try to provide administrator privileges to domain user.

Comment: Thanks @Jeaninez-MSFT - I know that with a local user ID if you runas Administrator, you don't need to grant additional privileges. If you don't, you can grant access to Manage Private keys explicitly and runas Administrator is no longer required. I am looking for the same sort of thing to add to the domain user.

Comment: this not related to privilege/user rights. also this is very unusual error from `AcquireCredentialsHandle`. this api usual return `HRESULT` with `FACILITY_SECURITY` ie `0x8009****` errors codes (`SEC_E_*`) interesting of course will be look this under debugger

Comment: @RbMm - hmm, so I check that the result value is not SEC_E_OK and then call GetLastError() which gives me ERROR_NO_SUCH_LOGON_SESSION. Is there more to be found in the return value too? I am second hand to the system that is struggling with this, so I need to add some code to capture whatever is useful if GetLastError's return code is not useful.

Comment: of course here `GetLastError` not useful and must not be called. error code direct returned by api call. what is returned by `AcquireCredentialsHandle` ?

Comment: Ok. I now know the returned code. It is 0x8009030e SEC_E_NO_CREDENTIALS. I think this means there is no private key in the certificate referenced. Is that correct?